# opening dial pad for calling number user want

Tags: ios

i want to open dial pad when user click on call button and then user enter phone number and call it

i know we can make call like this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://2135554321"]];
```

but i want to open dial pad and then let user enter number and press call button to call

if this is not possible then want to do something like my app open direct to dail pad then user call it and then it should redirect to my app

Comment: Do you mean you have a `UITextField` in your app and you want the number pad to appear for this text field?

Comment: no UITextField just click on button and dial pad will get open then user will enter number from that dial pad and then he will press call button and call with happen to that number which he has entered in dial pad.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No  you cant do this in iOS . iPhone SDK not gives you direct access to dial a numbers from the application .The one way to achieve this is 
take a text field

```
textfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypePhonePad;
```

and

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",textfield.text]]];
```

You have to see the format for entering the number.

Comment: *sidenote:* the URL should be `tel://your_phone_number`

Answer (score 3):

Why not create a UIView that has a "`UITextField`" and when the text field comes up, have the keyboard set to only be numbers (i.e. pretty much the same thing as the dialpad).

And once they are done entering in the number, *then* you can call the "`openURL`" line you have above.

Comment: yes sir thats what the last thing that i will do but if something is possible like i am saying