# how to open iPhone call screen keypad with number, when click on the button in iOS?

Tags: ios

I have call button in my view controller in my application. when i will click on call button, it will show my iPhone call keypad with some number.
       I am not getting any solution for this. Please help me.

Thank-you

Comment: possible duplicate of [opening dial pad for calling number user want](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563603/opening-dial-pad-for-calling-number-user-want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you think I am, I am not the `Popeye` that has supplied the other answer.

Right down to my answer. There are a couple of ways you can do this

```
// Pick one of the two ways from below, one will return you to the app afterwards the other will not.
// This version of of creating the number will open the dialer but will not return you to the app afterwards.
NSURL *phoneNumber = [NSURL urlWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", yourNumberString]];

// Whilst this version will return you to your app once the phone call is over.
NSURL *phoneNumber = [NSURL urlWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt://%@", yourNumberString]];

// Now that we have our `phoneNumber` as a URL. We need to check that the device we are using can open the URL.
// Whilst iPads, iPhone, iPod touchs can all open URLs in safari mobile they can't all 
// open URLs that are numbers this is why we have `tel://` or `telprompt://`
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneNumber]) {
    // So if we can open it we can now actually open it with
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneNumber];
}
```

Hope this helps if you have any questions please just ask.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone SDK doesn't gives you direct access to dial numbers from the app.So,you can't do this,but there is a way to achieve this.

-> Have a TextField(yourPhoneNumber) with keyBoardType UIKeyboardTypePhonePad.

-> `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt://%@",yourPhoneNumber.text]]];`

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: one question--->when i click on button it showing the dial pad.but not reopen mu application.

Comment: Welcome..once you enter the number add the method to the button click,once the button is clicked the number get called..Got it?

Comment: This will not open the dialer and return you to your app this will only open the dialer. To open and return you need to replace `tel://` with `telprompt://` (Different `Popeye` not the same as user who answered I have provided my own answer)