# How can I open the iPhone phone keypad programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I don't want to call a number. I just want to open the phone keypad programmatically.

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563603/opening-dial-pad-for-calling-number-user-want  see this link.

Comment: textfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypePhonePad; try this

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add UITextField and hide it and then call becomeFirstResponder:

```
var textField : UITextField //Create and set hidden to true
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.PhonePad //keyboardType
textField.hidden = true

//To Fire keyboard
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating @Hossam Ghareb's answer

```
var textField : UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)) //Create and set hidden to true

textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.PhonePad //keyboardType
textField.hidden = true

//To Fire keyboard
textField.becomeFirstResponder()

//Add to your view 
self.view.addSubview(textField)
```